# binary 2d dimension and packing

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the following problem. My main function reads some data like `1 2 3 4` and creates a list of integers that descend, `4 3 2 1`.  It also reads in a integer to set up a `bin` with which will be sized as `bin x bin` square of `0`'s.

Then it determines whether or not the boundary is okay. After this, I'm having trouble with the packing function. My code...

```
def isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
    if row + block > len(bin):
        return False
    if column + block > len(bin):
        return False
    else:
        return False
    if bin[row][column] == 0 :
        return True
    for r in range(row, row+block):
        for c in range(column, column + block):
            if bin[r][c] != 0:
                return False
    return True

def packing(bin, row, column, block):
    if isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
        for r in range(row, row+block):
            for c in range(column, column + block):
                bin[r][c] = block
```

To add on to make it more clear, my function is supposed to take in a `bin` value, for instance `6` and make a `6x6` grid of `0`'s.

```
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
```

Next it will take a list such as `4 3 2 1` and create 4x4 3x3 2x2 and 1x1 blocks. For instance, I've created a 5x5 bin grid. If I were to place `4321` it would look like:

```
44441
44440
44440
44440
00000
```

Since it can't fit a 3 and 2 it will go to the 1 and start from the top 0's.
Similarly, my code should print out the amount of unused 0's and blocks. Therefore, it doesn't need to use an optimal solution, just go in order from the set of blocks given.

So when the file block.txt is entered. It creates a list of integers from the file in descending order. block = [4,2,1]. If my bin = 5
it would create a grid like

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

Now when the 4 gets placed. A 4 block just means it's a 4x4 block. Since the 0's represent open spots it will place the 4x4 first.

```
44440
44440
44440
44440
44440
```

Now it will try to place a 2x2 block in the open 0's. However, there are no open spots for this block to go so it will go to the 1. Since the spot on the top right (0) is open, it will place it there.

```
44441
44440
44440
44440
44440
```

Comment: What is a `bin` value? Suggest you START with the question and post your whole code at the end.  Please provide a Short Self Contained Compilable Example of what's going wrong rather than every line of code in the whole project.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: I've updated it. The BIN is basically a grid. For instance, if I put in 5 as the BIN, it creates a 5x5 grid of zeros. The boundary would be the 5. If the row + block > 5 then it shouldn't be able to place anything beyond that and return a False.

Comment: The part of the code i'm having trouble with is the packing function, where I'm actually placing in the values from the list Block. So if my block = [4,3,2,1] It would start with a 4x4 block and place it in, then it would check to see if it can place a 3x3, 2x3, and 1x1. If it can't place a 3x3 and a 2x2, it would tell me that the 2 and 3 weren't able to be placed and the amount of zeros left.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this and condensing the question! Good job improving it to something that we can help you with

Comment: It's still vague what you are asking in reference to packing, I think you mean "insert".  Secondly, I can presume that bin is the bin, adn perhaps what row and column are, but what is 'block'. It would help if you actually demonstrated a call to your packing function. That's a key part of a complete example that's still missing.

Comment: I'll update the main problem.

Comment: I think you got the placement wrong in your example, though style is good.  (Too many rows of 4's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the very beginning of your `isSpaceFree`. You return `false` unconditionally.  The same problem occurs later from an unneeded check of `if bin[row][column] == 0: return True`

Remove them and you are good

```
def isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
    if row + block > len(bin):
        return False
    if column + block > len(bin):
        return False
    else:  # YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT THIS HERE
        return False #DITTO

    ## Nothing from here or below ever gets reached because of above commented lines
    if bin[row][column] == 0 :  ## you dont want this
        return True  ##because this is bad too and aborts and its already covered below
    for r in range(row, row+block):
        for c in range(column, column + block):
            if bin[r][c] != 0:
                return False
    return True
```